How do I bind an NSMutableArray to an NSPopUpButton
I have an NSPopUpButton defined in my view controller :
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton*    popUpButton;

this view controller also has an NSMutableArray which includes some objects of type NSDictionary, for instance:
NSDictionary *obj = @{@"name1": @"something",
                          @"name2": @"something else"};
    [myMutableArray addObject: obj];

I'd like my NSPopUpButton to reflect the contents of the name1 field of all elements contained in this array, but I have no idea how to achieve that with the bindings inspector in Xcode.
If I select the NSPopUpButton in the storyboard the following is shown in the bindings inspector:

am I supposed to use "Contents" or "Content Values" to achieve of what I want?(assuming it's even possible). I've seen some people use an ArrayController but I'd like to know if it's possible to go about this without it.

You can achieve this by connecting the Content binding with myMutableArray and the Content Values binding with myMutableArray.name1.
You may however run into another problem: adding objects to NSMutableArray  does not fire key-value notifications, so if you add values after the UI did load those will not display.
To work around this after modifications you can assign the mutable array to another instance variable and bind the UI to that array in an observable fashion:
// modify array
self.observedArray=myMutableArray;


Instead of the workaround, fire KVO notifications with willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey:.

Because mutable array and KVO can lead to odd and hard to debug issues, I tend to make the observed one an NSArray. Reduces surprises.

@Willeke can I avoid this by using an NSArrayController instead?

@IRP_HANDLER yes, if you only mutate the array using the methods of the NSArrayController.

@Willeke hey, I totally forgot about this... but can't you be a little bit more specific? Like,  I created an array controller and set a bind to to the NSArray with bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options: but I'm not sure yet how do observe the changes to the array, the documentation is a bit confusing .

@IRP_HANDLER the easiest way is to bind in IB. In code: [arrayController bind:NSContentArrayBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:@"myMutableArray" options:nil] (self is the view controller).

@Willeke this works only if I call [arrayController setContent: myMutableArray] every time I make any change to the array.

@Willeke seems like the workaround is calling [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"myMutableArray"] addObject: newObject]; every time I add a new element, I suppose this complies with KVO...
